# Putting together a string in javascript - ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, syntax

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function F2()
{
    for(i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
        ('zone'+i+'Data') = ('1'+document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Operate').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'OnTimeH').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'OnTimeM').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Duration').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Repeat').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Extra').value);

        ('op'+i).innerHTML = ('zone'+i+'Data');
        }
}
```

zone1Data, zone2Data, etc are declared externally. If I don't run the loop and use zone1Data = rather than ('zone'+i+'Data') = it works ok so I think it is something wrong with my syntax for this .... and probably also the last line too.

Any ideas how to do this??

Comment: Is `('zone'+i+'Data')` a variable name? I don't think that is allowed.

Comment: @Harry Zone1Data is a variable name, I thought I could put it together like this.

Comment: I see. By the way Patrick Evans has already posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
('zone'+i+'Data') =
```

is an invalid way to assign dynamic variables

use array notation with the variable name to create a new variable

```
window['zone'+i+'Data'] = "something";
this['zone'+i+'Data'] = "something"
someOtherObject['zone'+i+'Data'] = "something";
```

you can then use dot notation to access it

```
console.log( window.zone0Data );
console.log( this.zone0Data );
console.log( someOtherObject.zone0Data );
```

I would avoid the `window` one as that would pollute the global namespace

And as Ingo Bürk mentions it would be better to put these into an array

```
var zoneData = new Array();

for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
   zoneData[i] = ('1'+document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Operate').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'OnTimeH').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'OnTimeM').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Duration').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Repeat').value +
        document.getElementById('Z'+i+'Extra').value);
}
```

and each zone data will be accessible by its index

```
console.log(zoneData[1]);
console.log(zoneData[2]);
```

Comment: Better yet, avoid dynamically naming variables and simply use arrays. Dynamic variable names are terrible practice since names are an internal detail that should not matter to the functionality. If it does, rethink your design.

Comment: @Patrick Evans - Thank you I will try the array, as you and Ingo say it is a better way.